# What is the latin phrase for knowing a mistake and doing it anyway

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, meaning, motto

I am trying to remember a Latin quote that says something like

> I know I am wrong but I do it anyway.

I remember reading it in a book. It's not much to go on, but if someone knows it, it will be nice to remember it again.

Comment: This isn't the answer, but it's a good one: "Cuiusvis hominis est errare, nullius nisi insipientis in errore perseverare." Anyone can err, but only the fool persists in his fault. This is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(full)

Comment: Similar to Romans 7:15-19 (but it being a Latin quote is iffy)

Comment: @Liam: I am reminded of people whom I have known: drinkers; gamblers; druggies: lacking sympathy/ empathy, in my youth: "tu es stulto stultior!" = "You are more stupid than stupid!" Now, realising that addiction is an illness, a more enlightened approach. A one-word answer: "deditus" = "addicted"; or "deditus esse" = "to be addicted to". (Oxford). If there is anybody who knows that he is making a mistake, but does it anyway, it's an addict.

Answer (score 5):

I think I found the phrase, *Video meliora, proboque, deteriora sequor*. It is from Ovid's "Metamorphoses." I came across it while reading the Mayor of Casterbridge. Thanks for the comments, but I found it interesting because it doesn't mock the person for doing it; it's just tragic. Does anyone know the context of this phrase?

Comment: It would improve the quality of your answer if you provided a link to (or a quote from) the actual Ovid's text.

Answer (score 0):

Half the story is here:
Princess Medea falls in love with [Jason, who with the Argonauts' is trying to recover the Golden Fleece.](https://ovid.lib.virginia.edu/trans/Metamorph7.htm)

The Golden Fleece, which drew the Argonauts out of their comfort zone, came from the Ram which carried two refugee children from the Athamantic Mountains in Greece. One of the children, Hellé, drowned in the Hellespont.